# Where is an expository article on proving Newton's binomial theorem?

Tags: reference-request, power-series, binomial-theorem

Some years ago I found an expository article devoted to proving Newton's binomial theorem, which says that if $n$ is any real (not necessarily positive and not necessarily integral) number, and $|x|<1,$ then
$$
(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom n k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ \overbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}^{k \text{ factors}}}{k!} x^k.
$$
When $n$ is a nonnegative integer, all except $n+1$ terms vanish; otherwise none of them do unless $x=0.$

I *thought* this was in the *American Mathematical Monthly*, but via Google Scholar I can't find it there, nor any article in any publication matching that description.

Where is this?

Comment: Could it be https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313315313_Power_Tool_Newton's_Binomial_Theorem_Marks_350_Years  ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : It wasn't the same one as that, since it was before that time that I read it. I suspect it may have been published before 1970, or maybe even before 1950. Or 1920?

Comment: I have a 1911 Encyclopedia Britannica (inherited), which says Newton computed the co-efficients of the $q$th power of the power series for $(1+x)^{p/q}$ when $p,q\in\Bbb Z^+,$ and got the polynomial $(1+x)^p.$